# Why do I get "Error converting data type nvarchar to float." in my Sql?

Tags: sql-server, type-conversion

Please, observe http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6f14c/7

Here is the schema:

```
CREATE TABLE tmp1 (
  ts DATETIME NOT NULL,
  message NVARCHAR(128) NOT NULL
)
INSERT INTO tmp1 (ts,message) VALUES
('2015-06-24 00:28:18', '121a'),
('2015-06-24 00:30:18', '28.315b')
```

Here is the SQL statement:

```
;with data as (
    select ts,CONVERT(FLOAT, replace(message,'a','')) seconds from tmp1
    where message LIKE '%a'
)
select * from data where seconds > 100
```

Running it yields **Error converting data type nvarchar to float.**

Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server does not guarantee the order of evaluation of expressions.  What is happening is that the conversion is happening *before* the filtering, because it is pushed in to the part of the process that reads the data.

CTEs and subqueries do not affect this optimization.  The only way around it in earlier versions of SQL within a single query is to use `case`:

```
select ts,
       (case when isnumeric(replace(message, 'a', '')) = 1
             then CONVERT(FLOAT, replace(message,'a',''))
        end)
from tmp1
where message LIKE '%a' and seconds > 100;
```

In SQL Server 2012+, you can use `try_convert()` instead:

```
with data as (
    select ts, try_convert(FLOAT, replace(message,'a','')) as seconds
    from tmp1
    where message LIKE '%a'
)
select * from data where seconds > 100
```

Comment: Can't say I grasped the reason for the error, but your fix surely works.

Comment: @mark . . . If you are interested, you can read the documentation of how SQL actually gets executed.  Queries are compiled into an executable dataflow graph, and the correspondence between the executable and SQL statements is not always direct.

Answer (score 0):

Gordon's answer is actually right on! Alternatively, I think you could also use trim functions in SQL Server to do this:

```
;WITH data
AS (
    SELECT ts
        ,CONVERT(FLOAT, ltrim(rtrim(replace(message, 'a', '')))) seconds
    FROM tmp1
    WHERE message LIKE '%a'
    )
SELECT *
FROM data
WHERE seconds > 100
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6f14c/10/0)

Comment: At least to my mind Gordon's answer is a lot better. This just relies on the fact that adding more functions to the select part prevents it being evaluated earlier.

Comment: @JamesZ No disagreement there for sure! My intention was solely to give OP an alternative solution.

Comment: Yes, but unlike the accepted answer, your alternative solution doesn't actually fix what is wrong with the query. It's just a kludge that works with this data, but can you be sure it works always with different data too?